# C# not writing to rich textbox when reading from SQl

Tags: c#, sql, richtextbox

I'm trying to use the following code to clear a richtextbox, gather data from an sql database, and displaying through the richtextbox (rtbData) that the program is retrieving the information:

```
    public void readInData()
    {
        rtbData.Clear();
        rtbData.AppendText("...Retrieving Data From Database...");

        reader = dataCommand.ExecuteReader();
        if (reader.HasRows)
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                numbers.Add(reader.GetInt32(0).ToString());
                names.Add(reader.GetString(1));
                weights.Add(reader.GetDouble(2).ToString());
                statuses.Add(reader.GetString(3));
                times.Add(reader.GetDateTime(4).ToString());
                counter++;
            }
        }
        connection.Close();
    }
```

But whenever this runs the richtextbox never clears, and the message never appears. The strange thing is when I insert a messagebox.show() command directly below my rtbData.AppendText command, it works fine. I tried substituting the messagebox with a thread.sleep command but it didn't work. Any ideas? Thank you all in advance.

Comment: It's not 100% clear what the problem is. Don't forget that while your code is executing the SQL command your UI thread will be busy and so won't be able to update the UI.

Comment: You could call rtbData.Update(); to force a refresh, but as per @Daniel Kelley's answer it won't show if the main thread is already busy loading data from the SQL reader.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid blocking the UI thread, you can read the database asynchronously:

```
    public void readInData()
    {
        rtbData.Clear();
        rtbData.AppendText("...Retrieving Data From Database...");
        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            reader = dataCommand.ExecuteReader();
            if (reader.HasRows)
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    numbers.Add(reader.GetInt32(0).ToString());
                    names.Add(reader.GetString(1));
                    weights.Add(reader.GetDouble(2).ToString());
                    statuses.Add(reader.GetString(3));
                    times.Add(reader.GetDateTime(4).ToString());
                    counter++;
                }
            }
            connection.Close();
        });
    }
```

Bear in mind that readDatabase may execute on a separate thread, so you'll need to make sure that it is thread-safe.